# Flexslider: flex-active-slide class Not Being Added

Tags: flexslider

I'm using [Flexslider by WooThemes](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/), and I've noticed that the `.flex-active-slide` class, that's supposed to be added on the active slide, isn't being added on any slide apart from the first one.

Anyone had any experience with this or knows what might be the problem?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!